# Cast from String or Serializable value to a Class Object;

Tags: java

I have an enum Class `Property` and in some part of my programm I want to replace a `String` or `Serializable` value in my `Property`. How can i do that?

```
public enum Property {
    Autofocus,
    Bluetooth,
    Brand,...}
```

How can i assign value to `Property` using a `Serializable` value or a `String`:

```
Property property;
this.property = (Serializable) value;
```

or

```
this.property = "value";
```

instead of

```
this.property = Property.Autofocus;
this.property = Property.Brand; // ...
```

Comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: not quite sure i understand what you want... you want to put a string value in an enum?

Comment: yes, if i can, please say me how?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Property p = Enum.valueOf(Property.class, "Autofocus");
System.out.println(p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Every `enum` has an implicit method `valueOf(String)` that returns the enum instance with the specified name:

```
 Property p = Property.valueOf("Autofocus");
```

Note that this method throws an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) for unknown values.

Answer (score 1):

```
Property.valueOf("Bluetooth");
```

will take the value from string to the value of the enum if that's what you meant

The static methods `valueOf()` and `values()` are created at compile time and do not appear in source code. They do appear in Javadoc, though; for example, [`Dialog.ModalityType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) shows both methods.